# Extracting a specific param value from location.hash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have hash of the following locations:

```
#/something/default
#/something/url1/user2
#/something/url2/url3/user3
```

What is the regex to extract **only** the first param value that start after `something`, i.e. i need to extract: `default`, `url1`, `url2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and get the `2nd` array value:

```js
let str1 = '#/something/default'
let str2 = '#/something/url1/user2'
let str3 = '#/something/url2/url3/user3'
let str4 = '#/something'

console.log(str1.split('/')[2])
console.log(str2.split('/')[2])
console.log(str3.split('/')[2])

// You can use a fallback like this if there is no value:
console.log(str4.split('/')[2] || 'Nothing to see here')
```

However, if you have your heart set on regexp, you can use this:

```js
const regexp = /^#\/.+?\/(.+?)(\/|$)/

let str1 = '#/something/default'
let str2 = '#/something/url1/user2'
let str3 = '#/something/url2/url3/user3'
let str4 = '#/something'

console.log(str1.match(regexp)[1])
console.log(str2.match(regexp)[1])
console.log(str3.match(regexp)[1])

// You can use a fallback like this if there is no value:
console.log((str4.match(regexp) || [])[1] || 'Nothing to see here')
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex maybe doing the trick

```
(?<=#\/something\/)([^/\n]+)`
```